# PHP Auto-click catch/stop

Tags: php

I was wondering if it was possible to catch/stop someone from "auto-clicking"

I was having a think of ways it could be done. The best way is to check if the clicking time difference is the same between every click.

Anyone have any ideas to how I could stop someone auto-clicking on my website?

I use verification codes but I feel as if its annoying/unfair to those who don't auto-click.

If anyone has a script feel free to share!

Comment: Why oh why would you want to do this? If somebody can periodically generate click events, they can do so at random intervals.

Comment: Well I was thinking to have this and a verification code after a longer period of time.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you're trying to prevent. What kind of website are you running that you think people are "auto clicking"

Comment: A gaming website. Prevent players from cheating. Gaining things unfairly.

Comment: TKEP took care of those problems with a Flash interface with a moving button which disabled itself if you missed too much. I clicked that button too any times, about 6 million times too many :\

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out in which area of the button people usually click (you can do that by recording the clicks for a few hundred people). Most likely, you'll find it's always within the same area (maybe somewhere in the center).

Once you have this data, compare it to the area being clicked by the current user. If it's always in the exact same spot (to the pixel) or too random (compared to your sample data), it might be a bot. In that case, display a challenge - for example ask the user to click on some button placed randomly on screen. If he/it fails, you know it's bot.

Of course, you can also monitor the interval between successive clicks. If it's a naively implemented bot and the interval is always the same, you can also display the challenge to catch it.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, how would I find out where the button is being clicked?